# How do I pass data from scene to scene in phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game in Phaser 3 but I can't seem to find how to pass the score from a GameScene to a GameOverScene.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When calling `this.scene.start` you can pass optional data to the scene.

[`this.scene.start(key, data)`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.SceneManager.html#start__anchor), which has [an official demo](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cscenes%5Cpassing%20data%20to%20a%20scene.js).

You can use the `init` in a scene to retrieve the data.

So in your `GameScene` you might have something like the following:

```
this.scene.start('GameOverScene', { score: this.playerScore });
```

Then in your `GameOverScene` you should have something like the following:

```
init: function (data)
{
    console.log('init', data);
    this.finalScore = data.score;
}
```